Configure DHIS2 to add Javascript
How can I customize DHIS2 to add javascript file to autocalculate form's fields? Help me!
I tried to add autocalculate using GUI but seems GUI does not support that or maybe i just don't know. if there is a way to do this without using javascript then, help me, if not help me on how to add the javascript file into dhis2.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
